# Mysql SELECT WHERE id = ? AND url = 1, 0 or all

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system in which show messages, but the user has the option to see positive (1) and negative (0) messages, but also has a link where you can see all messages (1 and 0) and I can do this query?

**index.php?id=1&url=1**

```
<?php 
function mesage($id, $url) {
$db = DB::getInstance();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mesage WHERE id = ? AND url = ?", array($id, $url));
$results = $query->results();
return ($results);
}

$url = isset($_GET["url"])?$_GET["url"]:'Select 0 and 1';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$getmesaje = mesage($id, $url);
?>
```

As I can change the word "`Select 0 and 1`" in the variable "`$url`" to show all?

Comment: You can use `IN` like `url IN (?)` or `url IN (?, ?)`. You'd have to build it dynamically depending on the user in put.

Comment: I highly suggest to set default values for `$id` and `$url` and check condition based upon it.

Comment: @jeroen could you give me an example of code, apparently a reply could be better than the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

index.php?id=1&url=1    //  for positive

index.php?id=1&url=0    //  for negative

index.php?id=1          // for all

```
<?php 
function mesage($id, $url) {
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    if(empty($url)) {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mesage WHERE id = ?",$id);
    } else {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mesage WHERE id = ? AND url = ?", array($id, $url));
    }
    $results = $query->results();
    return ($results);
}

$url = isset($_GET["url"])?$_GET["url"]:'';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$getmesaje = mesage($id, $url);
?>
```

Comment: This will work in OP's case. we should make sure that `$id` and `$url` has valid values and will not break our query

Comment: Does not work, the value 0 is recognized as that $url does not exist and throws all (negative and positive) comments

Answer (score 1):

Prepare dynamic query depends upon user input . and use `IN` in where clause.

```
<?php 
        function mesage($id, $url) {

         $concatenate='';

         if(!empty($url))
         {

             $concatenate.= "  AND url IN(?)";

             $param = array($id, $url);
         }
         else
         {
            $param = array($id);

         }

        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mesage WHERE id = ? $concatenate ",$param );
        $results = $query->results();
        return ($results);
        }

        $url = isset($_GET["url"])?$_GET["url"]:'';
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        if(!empty($id))
        {
           $getmesaje = mesage($id, $url);
        }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE 1 :**
As per comment your correct when $url comes with 0 values it consider as empty . so it should be `if(strlen($url)>0){}` like this .

```
<?php 
    function mesage($id, $url) {

     $concatenate='';

     if(strlen($id)>0)
     {

         $concatenate.= "  AND url IN(?)";

         $param = array($id, $url);
     }
     else
     {
        $param = array($id);

     }

    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mesage WHERE id = ? $concatenate ",$param );
    $results = $query->results();
    return ($results);
    }

    $url = isset($_GET["url"])?$_GET["url"]:'';
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if(strlen($id)>0)
    {
       $getmesaje = mesage($id, $url);
    }
?>
```

Comment: This will work but we should make sure that `$id` and `$url` has valid values and will not break our query.

Comment: i just update my answers .is it okay now .thanks @RaviHirani

Comment: Does not work, the value 0 is recognized as that $url does not exist and throws all (negative and positive) comments

Comment: yes your correct when $url comes with 0 values it consider as empty . so it should if(strlen($url)>0){} like this @GePraxa and nice catch . now its work perfect